# windows server 2000

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2000

I have setup a secondary domain controller with server 2000 and would like to find out ways to confirm the functionality.I don't have ant error in the log but is there a way to understand if it is working beside unplugging the Ethernet cable from primary?

Comment: Temporarily disable Netlogon service on primary DC and see if 2nd DC processes authentication requests.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to monitor the DC long enough to determine if it’s being used or not.  Here are a couple tools I suggest.

Use NetMon or Wireshark to capture network traffic.  You can capture all inbound LDAP queries on a specific DC and build a list of source addresses.

You could try using AD Insight http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897539